# Using options.ids argument in viewer.loadModel method to select subset of objects in a model

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am trying to **select a subset of objects in a model**. The reason is that the model has lots of rebars and we only want to look at a few of them at a time. Loading all of them also makes the model slower.

So our idea is to **load the whole model** in order to get geometry data, and **filter out all rebars** (after OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT and GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT have been fired). Then we unload the model using *viewer.impl.unloadModel* and reload the model again, but now with **options.ids = ["all except rebar dbIds"]** as an argument to viewer.loadModel. Rebars are now excluded as excpected, but the remaining objects are no longer in order. By selecting **Windows** in the model browser I now get all sorts of random objects. [See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiHHo.png).

If I look at an object that is visible both when the full model is loaded and when a subset is loaded I see that the **data for the object has changed unexpectedly**. [The object now shows the properties of another object, located elsewhere in the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozoXi.png). (Don't mind the colors, they are different each time the model is loaded. The objects are the same wall).

I cannot see what I am doing wrong, could there be a bug?

Regars,
Torjus

Comment: which version are you using? (so I can try reproduce here)

Comment: Version 4.1. We haven't upgraded to 6 yet, but if that may solve the problem we can try.

Comment: ok, so I can reproduce it even on `v6` and I'm now investigating it

Comment: Great! Or not, depending on how you look at it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation (Viewer v6). If we load non-top IDs the Model Tree behaves unexpectedly on select. Our development team will look into it.

Comment: Hi, Augusto. Sorry to bother you. Have you got an estimated date for a fixed version of the viewer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't yet have a date. If possible, can you describe your case and business needs? you're welcome to send directly to forge.help at autodesk.com (please mention this stackoverflow question)